# How to override html file in magento 2.1

Tags: magento2

I need to customize Magento_Checkout module.

I have tried to copied that html files into my theme path but the override is not working

Override path mentioned in below

```
/app/design/frontend/Vendor/ThemeName/Magento_Checkout/web/template
```

But the file is taken from

```
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template
```

How to override this template html files?

Answer (score 6):

Suppose you want to overwrite the file:

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html
```

For this, you need to place the replacement file in:

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{Theme}/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html
```

If you do not see the changes after a page refresh, try to flush **JavaScript/CSS Cache** and **Static Files cache**.

Comment: I tried the same and added one extra class name to the outer li its not taking from the override code its still takes from vendor core checkout code , im using magento 2.2 , please let me know how to solve .

Comment: You can run `n98-magerun2 dev:asset:clear` if you use n98-magerun (which you should!)

Answer (score 6):

What you can do if something like this :

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/template/shipping.html': 'MyNameSpace_MyModule/template/shipping.html'

        },
    }
};
```

Basically you have to create your own Vendor module, and declare it in a `requirejs-config.js` into MyNameSpace/MyModule/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

Hope it helps!